# Two StreamProviders and two DocumentSnapshots

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

There are two StreamProvider under MultiProvider.

```
        StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>(
          create: (_) => GetUserInfoState().getUserDocSnap(),
          initialData: null,
        ),
        StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>(
          create: (_) => InListViewModel().stream,
          initialData: null,
        ),
```

**How do I separate the types of these two?**

**EDIT :**

```
      body: Consumer2<DocumentSnapshot, ProfilePageViewModel>(
          builder: (context, userInfo, model, child) {
        if (userInfo == null) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          String name = userInfo.get("name");
          String city = userInfo.get("city");
          String photo = userInfo.get("photo");
          String email = userInfo.get("email");
          Timestamp signUpdate = userInfo.get("signUpdate");
          String phone = userInfo.get("phone");
          String job = userInfo.get("job");
          Timestamp birthDate = userInfo.get("birthDate");
          int level = userInfo.get("level");
          bool userverified = userInfo.get("userverified");
```

If the returned type is not DocumentSnapshot, the .get() method does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would probably be to use a normal provider that holds an object with multiple streams.
But then you have to do without the features of a stream provider.

```
Provider<StreamHolder>(
      create: (_) => StreamHolder(),
      initialData: null,
),
```

with the object:

```
class StreamHolder{
      final Stream<DocumentSnapshot stream1 = GetUserInfoState().getUserDocSnap();
      final Stream<DocumentSnapshot stream2 = InListViewModel().stream;
}
```

and for using it:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
   initialData: ...,
   stream: context.read<StreamHolder>().stream1,
   builder: (context, snapshot){...},
)
```

If you absolutely want to continue using the features of the `StreamProvider`, you should create up to two different classes, so that the two streams are no longer of the same type, but at least one is not a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>`.

Comment: I did as you said. But I can't write StreamHolder() to create method. It gives this error:

The return type 'StreamHolder' isn't a 'Stream<StreamHolder>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: I have added some codes to the post. How can I use it there?

Comment: I have added to my comment. You can no longer use a consumer with this solution.